# How to take some data from an outter POST and POST it again to the same app on RoR?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post

Basically i'm receiving some data (variables a and h) from another site, and i would like to receive them and then make a POST with that data (the a and h variables that i already received) to my self app, i know that doesn't make a lot of sense but i need to do that.

I already coded the part where i receive the data from the other site.

MyRoute

```
  post '/', to: "pages#info"
```

MyController

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:info]
    protect_from_forgery :except => :info
    layout "second"

    def info
        if params[:initzarqkr].present?
          @h1 = params[:h]
          @a1 = params[:a]
          @h1_i = @h1.to_i
          @a1_i = @a1.to_i
        end
    end
end
```

My View (shown at / where the post is received)

```
<h1><%= @h1 %> | <%= @a1 %> </h1>
```

So i want to take that data i stored on the variables @h1 and @a1, re POST it to my app and then store it on some other variables in order to show them on my view at the route /, instead of the ones that i got on the post that i received from outside (even though i know that the values should be the same ).

How can i grant this?

Thanks very much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

What you'r talking about sounds like a redirect. A redirect is every time a GET request within Rails. Converting a POST to GET request has some drawbacks. You have to consider all the things which are different between a GET and POST request. One of the thing is the request lenght restriction.

In my point of view you have the following options:

- redirect to the wanted action and append the parameters to the redirect url
- handle the request directly within `info` and redirect after handling without params
- store the parameters within your `session` hash and redirect to the other action without params
- use a `net/http` or another libraray to post within `info` your data to an url and use a redirect
- create a view for `info` with a form which gets submitted automatically via javascript

If a  redirect with code 307 (repost data to new url) would work within Rails, I don't know.